# Cloudwatch putMetricData hanging within Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying set up a lambda to periodically query our queue service and report message counts back to Cloudwatch so we can monitor queue sizes.

The code all works when invoked locally using the serverless framework.  However when triggered from Lambda itself the request to AWS Cloudwatch never completes and the lambda times out.

```
import {Callback, Context, Handler} from 'aws-lambda';
import {CloudWatch} from 'aws-sdk';

const queueReporter: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
    // TRUNCATED - GET Queue counts

    const cloudwatch = new CloudWatch({region: 'eu-west-1'})
    const date = new Date();

    // convert queue data into cloudwatch metrics
    const metricData: CloudWatch.Types.MetricData = queues.map((queue): CloudWatch.Types.MetricDatum => ({
        MetricName: queue.name,
        Timestamp: date,
        Unit: 'Count',
        Value: queue.messages,
    }));

    console.log('add metrics'); // This prints out

    return await cloudwatch.putMetricData(
        {
            MetricData: metricData,
            Namespace: 'Queue_Messages'
        }).promise().then((response) => {
            const result = JSON.stringify(response);

            console.log(result); // this does not print out

            callback(null, result);

            return result;
        }
    );
};
```

I suspect this to be some kind of permissions issue as I saw a similar issue locally when I hadn't configured access keys on my laptop.
But the policy includes this statement which I believe should be enough

```
{
    "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

To access the queue's api this lambda has been added to a VPC and security group.  This Security Group however has no outgoing restrictions, only incoming.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would look at is simplifying the mismatch of async handling. You are awaiting a promise that is invoking the lambda callback but the lambda function is defined as async so AWS is expecting a promise to be returned. You should either define the lambda as async and ignore the callback, or define the lambda without async and use the callback.

Try this:

```
const queueReporter: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
    // TRUNCATED - GET Queue counts

    const cloudwatch = new CloudWatch({region: 'eu-west-1'})
    const date = new Date();

    // convert queue data into cloudwatch metrics
    const metricData: CloudWatch.Types.MetricData = queues.map((queue): CloudWatch.Types.MetricDatum => ({
        MetricName: queue.name,
        Timestamp: date,
        Unit: 'Count',
        Value: queue.messages,
    }));

    const response = await cloudwatch.putMetricData({
            MetricData: metricData,
            Namespace: 'Queue_Messages'
    }).promise();

    const result = JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log(result); 
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I've tired both forms (just async/await, just callback) with no joy.  The lambda just timed out after 6 seconds on each attempt.

Comment: What is the lambda timeout? Maybe increase it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a VPC endpoint to monitoring service in order to avoid timeout and connect to CloudWatch.

[VPC endpoint selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il1wA.png)

You can then mention the Private DNS name of the endpoint in the SDK configuration.

```
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({
    apiVersion: '2010-08-01',
    endpoint: `https://monitoring.${process.env.REGION}.amazonaws.com`,
    region: process.env.REGION
});
```